# Get more information about virus - decompile or disassembly

Tags: virus, disassembly

One message in my inbox has attachment with a zip file. Inside zipped file is file with extension ".pif". 
After opening file in hex editor I see that file is PE. Apparently someone added some code inside.

Gmail detects virus inside attachment.

I created virtual machine with Windows XP. I tried to run virus but nothing happen.

I'm really curious how does this virus work.

Can I identify in which language virus was written?
Is there a way to decompile or disassembly code inside ".pif" file?
Is there a ways to determine what is the name and type of virus?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_information_file I don't know anything, but did you try running it from the command line?

Comment: http://www.kaspersky.com/news?id=126

Comment: Yes i tried - nothing happend.

Comment: why do you think that nothing happened?  I bet an ProcMon would have detected plenty.

Comment: Processor usage has increased to 60% for less than 1 sec. There was created process with the same name like file with ".pif" extension but disappears after more less 2 sec... but I'm not going to study behavior of a virus, I want to know if there is a way to see the virus code or something which will be helpful to understand how does it really work.

Comment: You want to study the code but not the behavior?  You can't view the precompiled source code directly obviously, but you could view the assembly.  My first step to seeing how a virus works would be to use ProcMon to tell me what it's doing, but that's partially because I don't know assembly that well..

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that tool. It's really really usefull. This ".pif" file is creating a lot of files in many places including c:\Windows, and editing registry keys... . It will be lecture for tomorrow, because I'm too tired now. Thanks a lot it's good trace :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60876/discussion-between-luktar-and-mooing-duck).